# Possible to post URL and phone number to Google Places via API?

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

at www.movylo.com we're trying to integrate Google Places. We let merchants create a mobile store and want to post the store via APIs to Google Places. IT seems we can't post more than name of direction, so not possible to send URL, phone number, ...Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the same thing in the past but it looks like the only items you can add are the location, name and type, at least for now that is.